# How to I get project code using Platform.sh?

Tags: command-line-interface, platform.sh

I've inherited a project on Platform.sh. I need to get the project's code on my local machine.

Using the Platform CLI, I tried `platform project:get [project-id]`, but it keeps telling me that the project is already mapped to my user's root directory.

I can't navigate up one level and run it elsewhere since it says that the "already mapped" path is the root. I also cannot find any files related to the project.

How do I get these project files onto my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the Platform CLI, I tried platform project:get [project-id], but it keeps telling me that the project is already mapped to my user's root directory.

My guess is that you accidentally mapped the project when you were in your home directory. You didn't mention which OS you are on but in your home directory, as @zstolar indicated, there should be a hidden directory named `.platform`. Inside of that directory, among other things that you do *not* want to delete is most likely a directory named `local`. Inside of that directory will be a file named `project.yaml`. Delete the `local` directory, **and** the `project.yaml` file inside of it. Navigate to where you want to store the site's source code, run `platform get [project-id]` and now it should ask for the name of the directory to download the site code into.

If you're on windows let me know; I believe the location is slightly different and will have to look it up.

Comment: A little confused by your wording - Within the `.platform` directory, do I delete the `local` directory? Thanks!

Comment: correct. the structure should looks something like
`~/.platform/local/project.yaml`
You can safely delete the `local` directory and the files it contains. 
The `~/.platform` directory _shouldnt_ contain anything else except that `local` directory, and if so, you can delete the `.platform` directory as well. Just make sure to *not* delete `~/.platformsh` directory.

Comment: Is it `~` (user's home dir) or the project's root dir (e.g. `/var/www/project-abc`) ?
On my mac I have the `.platform/local` directory under the project itself, not in my home dir.

Comment: normally, yes. But since he mentioned: "`telling me that the project is already mapped to my user's root directory`" this means that at some point, the platform.sh cli created the `.platform/local` directory in their user's home directory (`~`). This can happen if you do `platform project:set-remote [project-id]` when you're in your home directory and don't realize it.

Answer (score 0):

@HWD if you inherited the project as a .zip file or similar, look for a local folder `.platform/local`.
It should be safe to remove it completely but at minimum you can find the project id in `project.yaml` and modify it.

Comment: then run `platform project:get` again